# usar f2 para clicar em botão com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte botão no meu site:

```
<button onclick='document.location="google.com.br"'>FINALIZAR</button>
```

Como faço para ele ser clicando quando eu apertar o f2? queria fazer isso usando jquery.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o evento keyup e verifique se o keycode é 113 (F2), ai só invoque o evento do elemento que quiser.

```js
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keyCode === 113)
    $('#elemento').trigger('click');
});

$('#elemento').on('click', function () {
  console.log('Disparado evento');  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="elemento" >Exemplo</a>
```

Comment: a onde consigo os códigos das teclas?

Comment: Pode dar um Google por "Key Codes", mas veja esse link: http://keycode.info/

Answer (score 2):

Você pode identificar o evento click no body e caso seja o f2 clicar no botão.

```js
$('body').keypress(function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (code == 113) { // 113 = f2
    $('#btn').click();
  }
});

function finalizar() {
  console.log("Fui clicado");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" onclick="finalizar()">FINALIZAR</a>
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Você também pode fazer desse jeito:

```js
document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;

function KeyCheck(e)
{
    var tecla = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
    
    if (tecla == 113) {
      alert('Pressionou F2') // Aqui você coloca seu clique no botão
    }
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Segue solução:

```
<button id="finalizar" onclick='document.location="google.com.br"'>FINALIZAR</button>

$(window).on("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 113) {
        $("#finalizar").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda.